# Can websites be opened without cursor detection by using cloud services or remote access tools?

Tags: gratis, remote-access, sandbox, windows-11

Is there a way to open a website and move the cursor to another screen or browser on my laptop without the website detecting it?
Typically, this can be achieved by using remote access tools to connect to a different system and open the website there.
However, this approach requires another system. I'm not certain if any cloud services offer this functionality.
**Things I tried:**
I tried using a tool called Jump Desktop to connect to my laptop remotely.
But it doesn't work.
Probably because it detects the local and remote systems are the same.
**Things that could work:**
windows-11 special edition has a sandbox thing, but I don't have it.

Comment: Did you try in a VM?

Comment: No, is there an easier way on a VM? Typically, downloading GB-sized .iso files seems complex. Unsure about cloud VMs.